# Sci-fi movie where a man keeps waking up in strange places

Tags: story-identification

It's a sci-fi movie from the late 60s to early 80s, in color, and the vague bits I remember are:

It was probably set in outer space. A man kept waking up in strange places and began to question his reality. On one of these occasions he woke up covered in some kind of webbing (or net) and seemed distraught as he removed it.  Then as he proceeded to explore his surroundings someone or something crossed the corridor behind where he couldn't see.

On another occasion he was being given electroshock treatment of some kind. I remember someone putting something in his mouth to prevent him biting off his tongue, then someone turned a knob and an oscilloscope went crazy and the man convulsed violently.

Those are the only things I remember from the movie.  I'm almost 38 and I saw this when I was in the single digits age wise.

Comment: The webbing part almost sounds like a Spider-Man movie but that's probably not it.

Comment: No this was an older movie, and sci-fi.

Comment: I figured, but thought it would be worth asking just in case. Good luck, hopefully you find it! :)

Comment: The electro shock scenario makes me think of this episode of Quantum Leap, although that was from 1991... http://quantumleap.wikia.com/wiki/Shock_Theater_(episode)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the "Tempests" episode (season 3 episode 9) frome the "The Outer Limits" TV-series from the 1990s. (Not to be confused with the black-and-white version from  the sixties)

> Commander Virgil is desperately attempting to deliver a serum to his
>   home colony, which is being devastated by a virus, Ellycia C. His wife
>   and young son are there. After his ship crashes into a gas giant, he
>   finds himself shifting between two realities: an ideal one, and one in
>   crisis.
>
> In the "bad" reality, the crash site turns out to be the interior of a
>   living being; while conducting repairs, Virgil is bitten by a
>   spider-like creature and its venom causes him to hallucinate. In the
>   "good" reality, the crew were rescued and delivered the serum; Virgil
>   is living happily with his family but is in treatment for Ellycia C.,
>   which is causing him to hallucinate. In each reality, he perceives the
>   other reality as a hallucination, and he is warned he could die if he
>   does not struggle against the other, "false" reality.
>
> Virgil reasons that his family are already safe if the "good" reality
>   is true, but they still need the serum if the "bad" reality is true;
>   so he embraces the "bad" reality to ensure their survival. He heads
>   for the colony in an escape pod and makes contact with his wife,
>   believing he is on track to save both the crew and the colony.
>   However, both realities are false; Virgil and the entire crew are
>   unconscious and being fed on by the alien spiders.

Comment: I have seen that episode.... It's unfortunately not the film I'm thinking of.   The one I'm thinking of I saw when I was seven years old or so, several decades before this episode was made.  That was a good one though.

Answer (score 0):

[*Rage of the Excalibrate* / *The Dungeonmaster*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dungeonmaster) had scenes where he woke up in new places and worlds. He then faced new adventures.

> Paul Bradford (Jeffrey Byron) is a skilled computer programmer who lives with his girlfriend, Gwen (Leslie Wing), and "X-CaliBR8," a quasi-sentient personal computer that Paul programmed and which he interacts with via a neural interface. Gwen is jealous of Paul's unusually close relationship with X-CaliBR8, to whom Paul has given a female voice, and fears that their relationship will be destroyed by Paul's reliance on X-CaliBR8 for his various day-to-day activities.
>
> One night, Paul and Gwen are both transported to a Hellish realm presided over by Mestema (Richard Moll), an ancient, demonic sorcerer who has spent millennia seeking a worthy opponent with whom to do battle. Having long defeated his enemies with magic, Mestema has become intrigued with technology, and wishes to pit his skills against Paul's, with the winner claiming Gwen. Arming Paul with a portable version of X-CaliBR8 (which takes the form of a computerized wrist band), Mestema begins transporting Paul into a variety of scenarios in which he must defeat various opponents. Most of the challenges involve Paul using his X-CaliBR8 wristband to shoot people, monsters, and objects with laser beams.
>
> After Paul completes Mestema's various challenges, the two engage in a final battle, which takes the form of a fist fight in which Paul kills Mestema by throwing him into a pit of lava. After Mestema dies, Paul and Gwen are transported back to their house, where Gwen expresses her acceptance of X-CaliBR8 and suggests that she and Paul get married.