# Guy with amnesia keeps waking up in different scenarios

Tags: story-identification

I have been trying to find this science fiction book for more than 20 years. It's a book from maybe from the 1970s.

A guy wakes up in a room. Looking out the window he eventually notices its a repeating scene outside, like a movie on a replaying loop. He keeps waking up in various scenarios. I remember something about his wife putting him through these scenarios trying to bring him back to himself, restore his memory of who he is.

If I'm not confusing this book with a different book, they are on a planet being consumed by some kind of moldy growth. They have to escape the planet. He needs to choose between something sleek and fast or something beefy and strong.

I used to think this was a Keith Laumer book, but I've since read every one of his books. But it's that genre of scifi. I've been trying to find this book for 20 years. Does any thread of it sound familiar?

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.

Comment: Related? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168067/sci-fi-movie-where-a-man-keeps-waking-up-in-strange-places

Comment: "He needs to choose between something sleek and fast or something beefy and strong. " To eat? To ride on? To marry?